# How to use breakpoints with my android studio "flutter pub run" package?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I'm developing a `build_runner` package for Flutter/Dart that I run with `flutter pub run build_runner build`. How do set up a debug configuration so I can use the debugger, set breakpoints, etc.? Below is my dialog shown for "Edit Configurations". I'm assuming I need to create a new configuration that executes `flutter` and adds the arguments `pub run build_runner build` but am not sure how to proceed?

[image]